# VLC logs show error to open TS file

Tags: h.264, vlc, mpeg2-ts

I have generated a TS file manually in C++. Whenever I try to open it with VLC, the VLC log shows the following and finally it is not playing. Can someone please help me analyse the errors ?

```
    core debug: adding item `big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts' ( file:///D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts )
    core debug: processing request item: big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts, node: Playlist, skip: 0
    core debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
    core debug: rebuild done - 2 items, index 1
    core debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
    core debug: resyncing on big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    core debug: big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts is at 1
    core debug: creating new input thread
    core debug: Creating an input for 'big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: Creating an input for 'big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: requesting art for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    core debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\USER~1.HOS\AppData\Local\Temp'
    core debug: `file:///D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts' gives access `file' demux `' path `/D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: specified demux `any'
    core debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts' file='D:\My Work\ffmpeg\WriteH2642TS_Modified V6\WriteH2642TS\data_source\big_buck_bunny\big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 12 candidates
    core debug: no access_demux modules matched
    core debug: creating access 'file' location='/D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts', path='D:\My Work\ffmpeg\WriteH2642TS_Modified V6\WriteH2642TS\data_source\big_buck_bunny\big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: looking for access module matching "file": 21 candidates
    filesystem debug: opening file `D:\My Work\ffmpeg\WriteH2642TS_Modified V6\WriteH2642TS\data_source\big_buck_bunny\big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: using access module "filesystem"
    core debug: Using stream method for AStream*
    core debug: starting pre-buffering
    core debug: received first data after 0 ms
    core debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 1000000 KiB/s
    core debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 6 candidates
    core debug: no stream_filter modules matched
    core debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 6 candidates
    core debug: using stream_filter module "record"
    core debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts' file='D:\My Work\ffmpeg\WriteH2642TS_Modified V6\WriteH2642TS\data_source\big_buck_bunny\big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: looking for demux module matching "any": 66 candidates
    core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
    core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
    core debug: searching art for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
    core debug: no art finder modules matched
    core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
    core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
    core debug: removing module "lua"
    core debug: searching art for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
    core debug: no art finder modules matched
    core debug: art not found for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
    ts debug: calculated bitrate (0bit/s) is too low or too high. min bitrate (500000bit/s) max bitrate (55000000bit/s)
    ts debug: Force Seek Per Percent: PCR's not found,
    ts debug: pid[4096] unknown
    ts debug: pid[256] unknown
    ts debug: eof ?
    core debug: using demux module "ts"
    core debug: looking for a subtitle file in D:\My Work\ffmpeg\WriteH2642TS_Modified V6\WriteH2642TS\data_source\big_buck_bunny\
    ts debug: DEMUX_SET_GROUP 0 00000000
    core debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.luac
    core debug: no meta reader modules matched
    core debug: `file:///D:/My%20Work/ffmpeg/WriteH2642TS_Modified%20V6/WriteH2642TS/data_source/big_buck_bunny/big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts' successfully opened
    ts debug: eof ?
    core debug: EOF reached
    core debug: finished input
    core debug: removing module "ts"
    ts debug: pid list:
    ts debug: - pid[0] seen
    ts debug: - pid[256] seen
    ts debug: - pid[4096] seen
    ts debug: - pid[8191] seen
    core debug: removing module "record"
    core debug: removing module "filesystem"
    core debug: dead input
    core debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
    core debug: nothing to play
    qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
    core debug: Destroying the input for 'big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts'
    core debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
    core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
    core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
    core debug: searching art for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
    lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
    core debug: no art finder modules matched
    core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
    core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
    core debug: removing module "lua"
    core debug: searching art for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
    core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\user.host-109\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
    lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
    core debug: no art finder modules matched
    core debug: art not found for big_buck_bunny_1496732948.ts
```

Comment: If we start looking from position "no access_demux modules matched", what is access_demux module? is this same as access unit?

Comment: also what is the meaning of "no stream_filter modules matched"? is it finding the streams present? But if I analyse it with ffmpeg, it says there are streams.